# Convert .txt file to JSON

Tags: json, api, type-conversion

I want to convert a fairly unorganized and unstructured [text](http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt) file to JSON format. I want to be able to use the city ID information. Is there anyway I can convert this to JSON?

**UPDATE:** I also found this solution after a while. Very simple way to get the JSON of any tab separated text file.

https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Comment: Please understand `.txt` is an extension and `json` is the data format. in  order to convert anything to `json` there has to be some sort of relation like `key-value` pair, `table-column` etc.. an unstructured text file can not be directly converted to `json` format.

Comment: Besides please also write what have you done or tried till now in the question

Comment: So if I find .txt file that looks like cityname: cityID, down the list. That could be converted then right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [tsv2json](https://github.com/jsonstein/tsv2json) this tool can reads a tsv file from stdin and writes a json file to stdout.

It's distributed in source file, to compile it you need to download [D compiler](http://dlang.org) and then run `dmd tsv2json.d`.

If you have more complex task there is another tool named [tsv-utils](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils-dlang)

Comment: Have no idea what any of that means, but atleast now I have a starting point. Thanks.

Comment: If you have not experience in programming you can start from riding this book http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/
Your task is very simply. You need only basic knowledges

Comment: Ok, I was hoping there is a way to convert the unorganized strings in a text file to JSON format. A way which would create a structure... so I will look into this. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

TSV to JSON in nodejs

```
var file_name = 'city_list.txt';

var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(file_name)
});

var isHeader = false;
var columnNames = [];

function parseLine(line) {
    return line.trim().split('\t')
}

function createRowObject(values) {
    var rowObject = {};

    columnNames.forEach((value,index) => {
        rowObject[value] = values[index];
    });

    return rowObject;
}

var json = {};
json[file_name] = [];

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    if(!isHeader) {
        columnNames = parseLine(line);
        isHeader = true;
    } else {
        json[file_name].push(createRowObject(parseLine(line)));
    }
});

lineReader.on('close', function () {
    fs.writeFileSync(file_name + '.json', JSON.stringify(json,null,2));
});
```